# UFW kill switch with exception for port 180

Tags: networking, firewall, nginx, ufw

So, I have a Ubuntu Server 18.04 that is connected to my home network, but uses a VPN. In order to block internet access, I blocked all connections of UFW like this:
- First all IPv6 connections were disabled
- Then I set UFW like this

```
#Whitelist Local Area Network
sudo ufw allow in to 192.168.1.0/24
sudo ufw allow out to 192.168.1.0/24

#Block All Incoming and Outgoing Traffic by Default
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw default deny incoming

#Whitelist VPN Port for VPN Establishment
sudo ufw allow out to any port 1194 proto udp

#Whitelist VPN Tunnel
sudo ufw allow out on tun0 from any to any
sudo ufw allow in on tun0 from any to any
```

Alright, now I have my home router, whose IP is for instance 1.1.1.1 set up with a free no-ip ddns, and has port 80 forwarded to ubuntu-server port 180 (so i can keep 80 closed).
On UFW I want to enable traffic in and out to this port, where my site is hosted (it is only a simple static html, for testing). So i set the firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow in 180/tcp
sudp ufw allow out 180/tcp
```

NGINX is configured as follows (I think this part is okay since if i curl 192.168.1.X:180 i get my main.html. The same for port 80 gets NGINX default page):

```
server {
    listen 180;
    server_name myhomerouter.ddns.net;
    root /home/user/site;
    index main.html;
}
```

UFW status shows this:

```
     To                         Action      From
 --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 192.168.1.0/24             ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 192.168.1.0/24             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 4] 1194/udp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 5] Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0           (out)
[ 6] Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 7] plexmediaserver-all        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 8] 180/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 9] 180/tcp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
```

I cannot connect with either telnet or browser, to my router port 80

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Changed the router port to 8000. It works if VPN is OFF but if it is ON, I cannot connect

**EDIT 2:**
Managed to track trafic on enp0s25, and i get the following:

```
13:02:41.678433 IP myrouterip.ISPSTUF.52975 > ubuntuserver.lan.180:Flags [S], seq 3926683823, win 65535, options [mss1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

A bunch of packages are sent but there is no length

Comment: Step 1 is to set up your server so you can connect from another machine on the same LAN. Step 2 is to set up your router's Port Forwarding. Go back to Step 1: Can you connect to Port 180 from another machine on your LAN?

Comment: IMHO (1) `ufw allow out 180/tcp` is not need. (2) Are you trying to connect to your router from an external IP (from the Internet)?

Comment: @user535733 Yes, curl 192.168.1.X:180 works from other machines in my lan. I edited the post

Comment: @FedonKadifeli (1) I think it is not needed either, but I setup just to see if it worked. (2) I tried with my mobile data (didnt work). From my network, curl myhomerouter.ddns.net:80 keeps spinning until it times out

Comment: You have demonstrated that your Ubuntu system is working properly. Your next step is to check your router's Port Forwarding, which isn't related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 So, I have only forwarded 80 to 192.168.1.X:180. If i do telnet myhomeserver.ddns.net 80 , it keeps trying to connect. If I telnet myhomeserver.ddns.net 443 (other not openned port) it gets automatically refused.

So, I think port forwarding is OK and it is a UFW issue. Maybe related to the kill switch

Also, with VPN off, which means no Internet, I can still ssh and connect locally to servers 180. So kill switch is effectively working for WAN connections

Comment: Your router may preventing you from using port 80. Try with another ("higher") port for example 1080.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thats it!! I swear I have used routers port 80 before. My router even has a place where you can select an http port forwarding and it automatically fills external port 80. Still they dont enable port 80

Comment: Probably there is a filter (firewall?) on your router that stops port 80.

Comment: I have another problem now.. I have now Sonarr (a local platform) working on port 180 (instead of the static html). However since I have ufw with IPv6=No, it does not allow me to connect to port 180 (since it needs ipv6). How can I make and exception to allow both ipv6 and ipv4 ONLY for port 180?